# network security in apt-get, rpm

Tags: linux

Basically my question is relation to every package manager. I'm interested to know that in package manager like apt-get,rpm etc., is there any network security while downloading any file, if yes what kind of it is and is it really required in os like linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are security measures, yes, obviously.

All packages in a repository are signed on the server side by a key in an asymmetric manner. That signature is checked by the client (your system) when downloading / installing packages. Only if it can be verified the package is accepted, otherwise an error is thrown. You certainly have seen that already a few times, for example when a repository got updated right whilst you download. Happens. But it is secure in that aspect.

You can very easily verify that yourself: setup your own repository (there are tutorials for that), import the key. Then replace a package stored there by some other file on file system level. Now try to install that file. You will see that it gets rejected because it cannot be verified.

The question whether that really is required is pretty strange. Why would one not want to secure that process? That would leave you vulnerable like the process of installing software on MS-Windows based systems!